# how can i get object from tag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have one view .in that view i have 2 buttons .

i know tag of that button . i want to change image of that button.

how can i change image by this tag?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[myView viewWithTag:myTag];
[button setImage:... forState:...];
```

Comment: The superview of the button. Why don't you look `viewWithTag:` up in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIScrollView * scView=(UIScrollView*)[self.view viewWithTag:20];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[scView viewWithTag:3];
```