# Register form with outlet collection and tags

Tags: ios, swift, iboutletcollection

I am new to Swift Language. I have knowledge in Web Development, but I need your help regarding this.

I need to create a register page with outlet collection. I have 4 text fields and have assigned tags to each of them. As I am going towards moving the cursor, from one textfield to another using beingfirstresponder(), it is not working and when I am printing tags like what I have assigned a tag to it's textfield, it is not always printing the same.

It is coming in a random order. Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var registerTF: [UITextField]!


@IBAction func registerTFTapped(_ sender: UITextField) {

   let tag = sender.tag
   print(tag)
    for tf in registerTF
    {
     if tf.tag == tag
     {

        func textFieldShouldReturn( _ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            nextTextFieldToFirstResponder(textField: textField)

            return true;
        }

        func nextTextFieldToFirstResponder(textField: UITextField) {

            if tf.tag == 0 {

                self.becomeFirstResponder()

            }
            else if tf.tag == 1 {

                self.becomeFirstResponder()

            }
            else if tf.tag == 2 {

                self.becomeFirstResponder()

            }
            else if tf.tag == 3 {

                self.resignFirstResponder()

            }

        }

        }
    }
}

//LifeCycle-Starts

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //#
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //#
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //#
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //#
}

//LifeCycle-Ends

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: I think you need make first responder the nex textField in the array, instead of your viewController which is self

Comment: You wouldn't normally use tags. Normally you would create individual outlets for each field. You don't want `self.becomeFirstResponder`; you need the next text field to become the first responder.

Comment: I have already created the individual outlets and that way it was working, but I want to work it with outlet collection. How can I get the next textfield using tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only will work if the order in the collection of TextFields is equal to the tags order

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var registerTF: [UITextField]!

    func nextTag(currentTag:Int)->Int{

        if(currentTag < registerTF!.count - 1){
            return currentTag + 1
        }
        return -1
    }

    func nextTextFieldToFirstResponder(textField: UITextField) {

        let nextTag = self.nextTag(currentTag: textField.tag)

        if(nextTag >= 0){
            self.registerTF![nextTag].becomeFirstResponder()
        }else{
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.nextTextFieldToFirstResponder(textField: textField)
        return true
    }

    //LifeCycle-Starts

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        for textField in registerTF {
            textField.delegate = self
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //#
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //#
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //#
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //#
    }

    //LifeCycle-Ends

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping, but it gives this Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'nextTag'

Comment: You need to add the method @Rob

Comment: Sorry, I am very new. I didn't got the method part. Can you please explain?

Comment: I will post a complete example of this, but first of all I need to have a good idea of what you want, you need pass from one to another textField when done button is pressed is that what you need?

Comment: Yeah, I have 4 textfields. They are connected to the view controller as outlet collection and you can see the code that action is also there. What I need is, when I press next on the keyboard after filling tf 1 it should move to tf2 and same should happen till tf4 and when at tf4 I click done, the keyboard should hide.

Comment: Let me know @Rob

Comment: Thanks. Was there any other way to use tags as in html we get name in form to get that particular input value as here tags were randomly floating.

Comment: @Rob `[self.view viewWithTag:myTag]` you can get an UI item by his tag, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794005/how-can-i-get-object-from-tag

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi @Reinier Melian, in here current Tag is a parameter right? I want to know how are you getting the value of current tag?

Comment: you need to edit the tag property on your textFields,  from 0 to count -1 each textField must have a tag, I can provide more info, let me know if you need it @Rob

Comment: Actually sir, I did add the tags to each textfield.